# Subview is not oriented properly

Tags: ios, subview, addsubview

I have created a subview which is used as a HUD in an iOS app. The app supports portrait and landscape display orientations.

The subview appears in portrait mode sometimes even if the mode is landscape. The subview is added by these lines:

```
self.infoHUDViewController = [[[InfoHUDViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoHUD" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:self.infoHUDViewController.view];
```

So it works very well if the subview is added in the `viewDidLoad` method. However, it does not work in landscape mode if the view is added in an `IBAction` method which responds to a button press. The subview appears as if in portrait mode (it appears 90° rotated, fills only the half screen width, and extends beyond the screen bounds).

What is really odd: In the init method of the subview's view controller the display orientation is correctly set to landscape. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a fix for this problem.

I added

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 480.0f, 320.0f);
} else {
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f);
}
```

to the `viewDidLoad` method. Now everything works as excepted in all situations.

Comment: You've hardcoded the screen size which is not a good idea for future devices including iPhone 5 and 6.

Comment: true... but this answer was also written long, long time ago. Now, I would not hardcode the frame sizes anymore.